# MariaDB - Inconsistent use of indexes for a SELECT and 2 JOIN

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, mariadb

I'm trying to recreate a local development environment from my production site. I'm using MariaDB 10.3.

I've replicated the production environment (structure, indexes and data) to my local machine but, unfortunately, I'm not getting performance comparable to the production.

### The problem

When I run the following query I get very different performance between the 2 env (12s on dev, 30ms on prod):

```
SELECT DISTINCT UPPER(LEFT(t.title, 1))
FROM elenco AS e
JOIN title_list AS t ON e.codice = t.release_code
JOIN login AS l ON e.gruppo = l.gruppo
WHERE e.materiale = 'film' AND l.id_utente = 1 AND t.title_type = 'ITA'
ORDER BY t.title
```

When I `EXPLAIN` the query I get inconsistent results among the 2 environment:

**PROD**

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | l | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 1 | Using temporary |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t | index | PRIMARY,title_type | title | 514 |  | 200 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | e | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | my_IUB.t.release_code | 1 | Using where; Distinct |

**DEV**

| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key | key_len | ref | rows | Extra |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | SIMPLE | l | const | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | const | 1 | Using temporary; **Using filesort** |
| 1 | SIMPLE | t | **ALL** | PRIMARY,title_type |  |  |  | 9788 | Using where |
| 1 | SIMPLE | e | eq_ref | PRIMARY | PRIMARY | 4 | my_iub.t.release_code | 1 | Using where; Distinct |

### Tables details

Table `elenco`:

```
CREATE TABLE `elenco` (
  `codice` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `materiale` varchar(25) NOT NULL,
  `gruppo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `autore` int(10) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`codice`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=8908 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

Table `title_list`:

```
CREATE TABLE `title_list` (
  `release_code` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(512) NOT NULL,
  `title_type` varchar(64) NOT NULL COMMENT 'Can be: ORIGINAL or ITA',
  `last_modify` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp() ON UPDATE current_timestamp() COMMENT 'It''s the time the release title was modifid',
  PRIMARY KEY (`release_code`,`title_type`),
  KEY `title` (`title`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `title_type` (`title_type`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci COMMENT='It''s the list of all titles';
```

Table `login`:

```
CREATE TABLE `login` (
  `id_utente` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` varchar(65) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'Recovery email',
  `passw` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  `permessi` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 99,
  `gruppo` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 1,
  `attivazione` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `ultima_modifica` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `online` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `last_time_online` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
  `premium_1f` varchar(256) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id_utente`),
  UNIQUE KEY `attivazione` (`attivazione`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user` (`user`),
  UNIQUE KEY `user_2` (`user`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=66 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci;
```

title_list has the same indexes for both environment `SHOW INDEXES FROM title_list;`:

| TABLE_NAME | NON_UNIQUE | INDEX_NAME | SEQ_IN_INDEX | COLUMN_NAME | COLLATION | CARDINALITY | SUB_PART | PACKED | NULLABLE | INDEX_TYPE | COMMENT | INDEX_COMMENT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| title_list | 0 | PRIMARY | 1 | release_code | A | 9788 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| title_list | 0 | PRIMARY | 2 | title_type | A | 9788 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| title_list | 1 | title | 1 | title | A | 9788 |  |  |  | BTREE |  |  |
| title_list | 1 | title_type | 1 | title_type |  | 1 |  |  |  | FULLTEXT |  |  |

#### What I tried?

- Switching to MariaDB 10.4 or greater didn't solve my problem
- Dropping and recreating indexes didn't solve my problem
- Forcing use of indexes on `elenco` and `title_list` partially improved performance (from 12s to 3s)

#### Fun facts

- The development environment (the slower one) is on intel i7 with 16GB RAM and SSD
- The production environment (the faster one) is on a Raspberry pi 4 with 4GB RAM and using a mechanical HD plugged via USB

Comment: without knowimng the CREAE TABLE with indexes, nobody can help you

Comment: @nbk Thanks for the suggest, added the CREATE TABLE for all the 3 tables

Comment: 12s to read 2x10k rows seems unreasonable. I doubt your problem has much to do with the actual query, but that there is something going on with your configuration or your setup. E.g. a default configuration might not be optimized for "myisam", which you apparently use (and make sure you use myisam on both servers - or better, don't use it at all), so you may want to compare the configuration. Can you also check some other queries (on other tables), do they show a similar performance degradation?

Comment: you should add all columns in the where clause also as combined Key, you can also use independent keys, but you should test also the combined

Comment: https://mariadb.org/mariadb-30x-faster/ - ANALYZE TABLE perhaps

Comment: @danblack Unfortunately the analyze table didn't help

Comment: @Solarflare Yes, I tested and I had bad performances also on other tables so I switched from MyISAM to InnoDB. Automagically the DEV DB is using the correct indexes and performance are in line with PROD. Now I have to make some more test before switching to InnoDB on Prod. Thank you very much!

Comment: @nbk I didn't get the suggestion, how can I improve the query?

Comment: for example materiale belongs into an index, you can test (codice, materiale) as primaey key or as separate index, and the same goes for the other tables

Comment: @Timmy Just to make sure: while innodb is the more modern and preferable system, you should not make changes on a working prod just because of my flappy comment (although you should consider it longterm, and I assume that is what you meant. If you test, especially check effects of transactions and the slightly different behaviour of fulltext searches). But the successful change on dev indicates that it seems to indeed be a configuration/setup issue, not something particular to that query. You may get a similar improvement if you copy the (myisam) configuration from prod to dev.

Comment: @Solarflare I absolutely agree, I hope my next version of software will use InnoDB by default for all tables, but, of course, I need to widely test it before

Comment: Do dev and prod have the same number of rows?

Answer (score 0):

These indexes may speed up the query on both servers:

```
t:  INDEX(title_type, release_code, title)
e:  INDEX(materiale, codice,  gruppo)
l:  INDEX(id_utente, gruppo)
```

If the data is different (between dev and prod), that could explain the difference timing and query execution plan.  Please provide `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` from each machine.

And do switch to InnoDB.  Doing lots of `DELETEs` or `UPDATEs`, etc, can fragment MyISAM worse than InnoDB.

Suggest changing to `ORDER BY 1` -- since you are really only ordering by the uppercase of the first letter of `title`.

Run `ANALYZE TABLE` for each table on each machine.  This *may* make them work the same and/or *may* speed up one or both.

Comment: (I made some substantive changes to my Answer.)